# how do I place 2 buttons on top of each other while keeping them centered?

Tags: html, css

I would like to put 2 buttons on top of each other while still keeping both of them centered. I managed to put them on top of each other through the display: block, and through the flex-direction: column. However, I still don't know how to center them. The text-align doesn't seem to work. could somebody explain to me why this doesn't work, please?

```
button{
    border: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px ;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-group{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}



#increment-btn{
    background: darkred;
}

#save-btn{
    background-color: green;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button id="save-btn" onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
        <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try to use class instead of native html element or id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use   `align-items: center;` , it is a `flex-direction: column;`, so it will be align on the horizontal axis :)

```css
button {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#increment-btn {
  background: darkred;
}

#save-btn {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="save-btn" onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
  <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
</div>
```

Aside, flex or grid children do not really need to be reset to block if it is an inline element , they become part(cells) of the generated grid . (float is also ignored)

Comment: I do exactly the same, nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `align-items: center;` in your `.btn-group` instead of `text-align: center;`.

For further information [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) site is very helpful.